# Searching text files to get specific double

Tags: java

I am writing a bank account program for my Comp Sci class, and need to search a .txt file for a account number a user enters (which is an int) and then pull out the next row which is the balance. i.e. the user enters the account #12345679 and i need to pull out the balance of it. Below is an example of the txt file

```
12345678
133.87
12345679
500.00
12345670
123.00
```

So far I have and I know that i'm going to have to put how to get the balance in the if statment

```
while (accountTries < 3)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter your 8 digit account number");
            accountNumber = console.next();
            accountLength = accountNumber.length();
            while (in.hasNextInt())
           {
                line = in.hasNextInt();
                if (accountLength == 8 && line == accountNumber  )
                    {
                    accountTries = 3;           
                    }
            }
            System.out.println("INVALID ACCOUNT NUMBER.");
            accountTries++;
            }
        }//End of while loop
```

Comment: and what have you got so far, and/or what is your specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do... but this doesn't seem right:

```
line = in.hasNextInt();
```

Shouldn't you be getting the value here? You're just testing to see if there's anything there, like you did in the "while" condition.

Comment: Why I wrote that line is to  for the account number then the next line  under it has the balance. So i'm not sure how to pull out a double from the next line. I very well might be over complicating this.

Answer (score 0):

```
outer: while (accountTries < 3)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter your 8 digit account number");
    accountNumber = console.next();
    accountLength = accountNumber.length();
    while (in.hasNextLine())
   {
        line = in.nextLine();
        result = in.nextLine();
        if (accountLength == 8 && line.equals(accountNumber))
            {
            accountTries = 3;           
            break outer;
            }
    }

    System.out.println("INVALID ACCOUNT NUMBER.");
    accountTries++;
    }
}//End of while loop
```

I used a labeled break to get out of the outer while (you can do the same with if statements and a done flag but I'm to lazy to do that here)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply read file to String and split it by line separator(\n or \n\r).
For example :

```
String fileContent = //read String from file;
String[] elements = fileContent .split("\n");

for(int i =0; i< elements.length; i++){

if(i%2 ==0){ 
   //get account number
}else{
  //get balance
}

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to use arrays .... My prof is a total bitch and will fail me. I tried to do recursive method on an earlier assignment and she failed me because we had not learned it yet...

Comment: @Pnchappy92 In that case you can use BufferedReader when reading file and call bufferedReader.readLine ()  and keep counter that increment after each reading , if  counter %2 = 0 ?  //get account , otherwise get balance